# Set width of TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, width, textfield

When using TextField, I want to set it on a fixed width regardless to the shown text length, e.g. field width for "123456789", even if the content is only "1".

```
TextField("0", text: $username)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    .frame(width: 120)
```

I didn't find anything to set the width. Using frame only affect the surrounding frame, but I want to set the width of the TextField itself. So the visible width should be wider than the content of it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the .frame() modifier before applying the .textFieldStyle() modifier.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var username = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("0", text: $username)
            .frame(width: 120)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

There you go!